# Can't access ViewBag data in Facebook App

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Facebook app that is giving me fits. I basically have an app that once the user has liked the app, they can continue through the app. Using the Facebook Javascript API, it will see if the user has logged in, and if not allow them to log in. I pass rather or not they "like" the page from the controller, as well as their language (English or Spanish) to the view via the ViewBag object.

This works both locally and from the staging server; however I have to disable the like check in the view, but the language and like is passed in the viewbag.

I placed language in the view like

`<p>The user's language is @ViewBag.lang</p>`

and

`<p>They like the page? @ViewBag.likes`

Like I said, both locally and at the staging server it works; but nothing gets passed through to the Facebook app. I have a conditional check to see if the user likes the page in javascript like:

`var likes = @ViewBag.likes`

In Facebook, using the console I see that the data isn't passed as well as the before mentioned debugging I tried doing.

I am very new to MVC; is there something I need to enable to make it work through Facebook?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you paste a bit more code? I'd also suggest checking out the http://csharpsdk.org/ -- you can then pass the access token from the authResponse and get a bevy of information that you can then populate your ViewBag with.

Comment: Thanks for replying; I first started out trying the csharpsdk, but a coworker already had a working solution. The controller is simply returning a ViewBag object. If I was to say ViewBag.Animal = "cat", and then try to view it through the app by saying @ViewBag.Animal, it's blank. Not to be snarky, but I don't think the issue is with the way I'm connecting to Facebook, but rather some kind of ViewBag problem.

Comment: Are you trying to set the ViewBag in C# or in inline html code?

Comment: No, the ViewBag data is set in the controller; I need to access the data in the view.

Comment: Are you setting the ViewBag value directly before the action is loaded? ViewBag doesn't persist beyond the next action.

Comment: Yes, I am setting the ViewBag value before returning the View. This is all working from both localhost and on the staging server the app is hosted from; once it runs in the Facebook app page, it breaks... Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Well the issue is that the Facebook canvas sends an initial POST, this was hitting my POST instead of the GET which was setting these values. See here:

[Does Facebook open a canvas app with a Post request? It's causing havoc with my MVC actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353261/does-facebook-open-a-canvas-app-with-a-post-request-its-causing-havoc-with-my)

Thanks!